# Why seen cross-sections of objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Why seen cross-sections of objects? I have different meshes on objects with materials (with Standard Shader rendering mode = opaque)
http://prntscr.com/9vt7no

http://prntscr.com/9vt7px

Comment: You mesh is bad. You not need the internal polygons. You can remove this to improve the mesh and render results. Adn ensure that your normal direction is right and not flipped.

Comment: Can you double check that tris in these areas are not overlaping? From your wireframe image can't be said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that the backface culling is set wrong (for your meshes). If it is culling front facing triangles while showing the backfacing ones, the effect would be about what you have shown on the pictures.

Either flip the cull mode of your shader, or flip the triangles in your mesh.

For a quick test your can just disable backface culling. If it looks right then, you know that your issue is about the culling.

Comment: From your other question I gathered that you are in fact generating the meshes yourself. In this case I am actually convinced that your triangles are flipped the wrong way. You can easily fix this by changing your triangles vertices from V1,V2,V3 to V1,V3,V2.